# How to customize the QTextEdit boundaries?

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qframe, qstylesheet

I'm very new to the designer mode of Qt.

I want QTextEdit to have a look exactly as shown in this [image]. **"High Score"** should be part of the boundary. How is it possible to customize the qtextedit like this? Is it through QStylesheet I have to do that or it is possible to be done through the designer option of QtCreator? If it is through QStyleSheet, what is the command code for that?

Thanks

Comment: Should `high scores` title be part of it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to just configure `QTextEdit` to behave as you need it.

It may be much easier to draw the Border with the HIGH SCORES string in a widgets `paintEvent()` and place a `QTextEdit` with transparent background and borders into it. Set the margins of the layout big enough for the border to be visible around the `QTextEdit`.